# How can I modify the format block dropdown list of Jodit editor?

Tags: jodit

I would like to modify the "insert format block" dropdown. By default it has Normal, H1, H2, H3, H4 and Quote. How can I take out H1 and Quote and add H5 and H6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Jodit.defaultOptions.controls.paragraph.list = {
    // your key-value pairs
    //
    // defaults are:
    // p: 'Normal',
    // h1: 'Heading 1',
    // h2: 'Heading 2',
    // h3: 'Heading 3',
    // h4: 'Heading 4',
    // blockquote: 'Quote'
};
```